# "Cannot read property 'type' of undefined" in redux store for action defined in external package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux, react-redux

As part of my ongoing project to learn React (I'm natively an ASP.NET guy) I've hit this issue. I have a suite of React apps in which I want to use some common UI elements, so I've attempted to break these out into a separate npm package. For the shared components themselves this has worked fine.

However, some of these components depend on redux actions to operate, so I've tried to bundle these actions and a reducer function into the external package. Here's a simplified version of my `actions\index.js`:

```
export const SNACKBAR_MESSAGE = "SNACKBAR_MESSAGE";
export const SNACKBAR_HIDE = "SNACKBAR_HIDE";

export function showSnackBarMessage(message) {
    console.log('hit 1');
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        console.log('hit 2');
        dispatch(hideSnackBar());
        dispatch({
            type: SNACKBAR_MESSAGE,
            message: message
        });
    }
}

export const hideSnackBar = () => {
    type: SNACKBAR_HIDE
};
```

And this is `reducer\index.js`:

```
import { 
    SNACKBAR_MESSAGE,
    SNACKBAR_HIDE
} from "../actions";

const initialState = {
    snackBarMessage: null,
    snackBarVisible: false
};

export default function UiReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SNACKBAR_MESSAGE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { 
                snackBarMessage: action.message,
                snackBarVisible: true
            });
        case SNACKBAR_HIDE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { 
                snackBarMessages: '',
                snackBarVisible: false
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

This is the same code that worked fine when part of the original project. These are exported by my package's entry point file like this:

```
// Reducer
export { default as uiReducer } from './reducer';

// Actions
export { showSnackBarMessage as uiShowPrompt } from './actions';
export { hideSnackBar as uiHidePrompt } from './actions';
```

Then in my consuming project, my default reducer looks like this:

```
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { uiReducer } from 'my-custom-ui-package';
// Import local reducers

const reducer = combineReducers(
  {
    // Some local reducers
    ui: uiReducer
  }
);

export default reducer;
```

The problem is when I try to dispatch one of these actions imported from my external package. I include the action, e.g. `import { uiShowPrompt } from "my-custom-ui-package";` and dispatch it like `dispatch(uiShowPrompt("Show me snackbar"));` then I see the two console messages (`hit 1` and `hit 2`) displayed, but then the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
>
> ```
> at store.js:12
> at dispatch (applyMiddleware.js:35)
> at my-custom-ui-package.js:1
> at index.js:8
> at middleware.js:22
> at store.js:15
> at dispatch (applyMiddleware.js:35)
> at auth.js:28
> at index.js:8
> at middleware.js:22
> ```

The store itself looks like this:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { browserHistory } from "react-router";
import {
  syncHistoryWithStore,
  routerReducer,
  routerMiddleware
} from "react-router-redux";
import reducer from "./reducer";

const loggerMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    console.log("Action type:", action.type);
    console.log("Action payload:", action.payload);
    console.log("State before:", store.getState());
    next(action);
    console.log("State after:", store.getState());
};

const initialState = {};

const createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
  applyMiddleware(
    loggerMiddleware, 
    routerMiddleware(browserHistory), 
    thunk)
)(createStore);

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer, initialState);

export default store;
```

I'm afraid I don't understand this error. I don't see what I'm doing differently other than essentially moving identical code from my local project to an npm package. Since neither the actions nor reducer actually depend on redux, my npm package doesn't itself have a dependency on `react-redux`. Is that a problem? If there's anything else I could share to help you help me just let me know. Like I say, I'm still fairly new to all this so clearly there's something I'm not getting right!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem might be in declaration of **hideSnackBar** function

```
export const hideSnackBar = () => {
    type: SNACKBAR_HIDE
};
```

Here the function is trying to return an **Object Literal** from **Arrow Function**. This will always return **undefined**. As the parser doesn't interpret the two braces as an object literal, but as a block statement. Thus the error, Cannot read property 'type' of undefined as store is expecting an action with property type.

Replace code like this and see if it works.

```
export const hideSnackBar = () => ({
    type: SNACKBAR_HIDE
});
```

The parentheses forces it to parse as Object Literal. Hope this helps

Comment: Absolutely right. Thank you for the detailed explanation too. Of course now I remember removing those parentheses when I created the package, thinking I was _tidying up_! Next time I'll be more careful.

Comment: I've run into a somewhat similar issue described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63622988/unable-to-import-reducer-from-react-library-npm-package-redux - if possible, your inputs would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I had exported it like

```
export default userReducer();
```

and not like this:

```
export default userReducer;
```

Just get rid of that `()`

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it was case of wrong order in receiving the arguments when using `redux-thunk`.

```js
// wrong argument order
const anAction = () => (getState, dispatch) => {...}

// correct one
const anAction = () => (dispatch, getState) => {...}
```