# Unable to import reducer from React library npm package (redux)

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux

I'm trying to create a React library npm package for import into other modules.

The package uses redux and the intention is to expose the reducer, so that it can be loaded by the consuming application.

I've used `create-react-library` to construct the basic library infrastructure.

In simplified terms, my structure is as below. The full repo can be seen [here](https://github.com/MatinF/config-editor-base).

**Library application**

```
src/
-- editorBase/
   -- actions.js
   -- Component.js
   -- reducer.js
-- index.js
```

My `index.js` looks as below:

```
import EditorSection from './editorBase/EditorSection'
import editorReducer from './editorBase/reducer'

export {editorReducer}
export {EditorSection}
```

My `reducer.js` looks as below:

```
export default = (
  state = {
    ...
  },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionsEditor.CONSTANT:
       ...
    case ...:
       ...
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

---

**Consumer application**
My consuming app's `index.js` looks as below:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import configureStore from './store/configure-store'
import App from './App'

const store = configureStore()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

My consuming app's `reducers.js` looks as below:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import {editorReducer} from 'config-editor-base'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  editorReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

My consumer's `configure-store.js` looks as below:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import reducers from "../reducers";

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers, initialState);
  return store;
}
```

---

**The issue**
When I try to run my consumer application, I get an error which states that variables related to the redux state are undefined. I've verified that if I modify the `reducers.js` file in the consumer app to use a relative import as below, it works as intended. However, this only works as a 'test' in the react-library-app setup:

```
import editor from 'config-editor-base/src/editorBase/reducer'
```

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved. It turned out in my `actions.js` I was exporting constants named `editor/...` which meant I had to export my reducer so that it was named `editor` for it to work.

Updated index.js:

```
import EditorSection from './editorBase/EditorSection'
import editor from './editorBase/reducer'

export {EditorSection, editor}
```

Updated reducers.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import {editor} from 'config-editor-base'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  editor,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Its a little off-topic but is there someway to use `useDispatch inside a npm library` and using the store of the react app?

Answer (score 0):

this is the right way to import redux and react-redux from libraries.

`npm install redux react-redux`

now import createStore in your store.js

`import { createStore } from 'redux';`

Now import Provider in your index.js

`import { Provider } from 'react-redux';`

Use this as resource :
https://www.codementor.io/@rajjeet/step-by-step-how-to-add-redux-to-a-react-app-11tcgslmvi

Comment: I've updated my consumer app details to include a more full picture of the redux setup. It should be added that I've verified the full redux setup in my "full application" where it's working as intended - so my challenge is mainly on how to 'carve out' part of my app into an npm package and then to correctly "reimport" it into my overall app.